# Select values from not empty column in mysql

Tags: mysql

> Table Photos-------

```
photo1  imagem1.jpg
photo2  imagem2.jpg
photo3  empty
photo4  empty
photo5  enpty
```

I have a table, with 5 columns who represents photos.
So,
I want to select * from table, all columns... but if one or more of them are empty, I don't want to select. is that possible?

For example, if I do this

```
Select * from table Photos where photo1 is not null, and photo2 is not null, and photo3 is not null and photo4 is not null and photo5 is not null
```

that is not possible, because if one of them are empty... the select don't give any values.

anyone know another way?

and also, i need that because if I want to do this:
the problem is.... when I use php for example this

```
if($project['photo5']!='' and $project['photo5']!=null){ 
(here i show the picture)
}
```

If the row is empty... php is ignored and show a error image

Comment: by empty do you mean the string 'empty' or do you mean NULL? and what's the table structure for photo table it appears to be 2 columns.  If so what are the column names? If there are 5 columns called photo1 through photo5 then I have a different approach.  based on the PHP and query there are 5 columns...

Answer (score 1):

`Concat()` will return null if any one of the values concat is null  ([mySQL DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)) Since you want to only show records where none are null concat together and check for not null.

```
Select * 
from table Photos 
where concat(photo1,photo2,photo3,photo4,photo5) is not null
```

AND... your approach should work if you used `or`'s instead of `AND` and possibly a  `not`.  I just find the above easier to read.

Comment: if I have photo1, photo2, photo3 with content and photo4, photo5 empty
i need that my select, only return the photo1, photo2, and photo3... not all another empty content

Comment: the problem is.... when I use php for example this  
if($project['photo5']!='' and $project['photo5']!=null){ 
(here i show the picture)
}
If the row is empty... php is ignored and show a error image

Comment: A select statement will always return the columns in the select.  So if you want photo1-5 columns you will get 5 columns.  The application (phP) will need to handle the absence of data for the column.